# Content centering after table cell height is dynamically increased in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have two columns in a Table but I also want the second column to be able increase its height dynamically when data is inserted without affecting the height of the first column.

The problem is that everything gets centered in each cell of that row.... How can I keep this from happening?

Answer (score 4):

Use divs instead. Tables do not provide you with such a behaviour.
Nested divs and float equal to left or right will help you to setup the height and width not like in table case. Because table was designed to be rendered by a line.

Comment: I fixed the problem... I just added this 

vertical-align: top;

Comment: Yes and if your right cell (td) is of height 200px, and the left one is of just one line (< 30px), then it will take a lot of unneeded space. Therefore better to use divs :)